# Can I create border-bottom without diagonal corner?

Tags: html, css, border, flat

I want to create a box with different color, left,right and top color red and bottom color is grey but I want flat bottom-border of box

**HTML**

```
<div class="ts"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ts {    
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-width:10px 10px 20px 10px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#f00 #f00 #ddd #f00;
}
```

When I create it with above code, It seems like this

[image]

But I don't want bottom-border as diagonal corner, I want it as;

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/3jHG8/

Is there an easy way to do it as crossbrowser?

Comment: You could try a pseudo element, or does it have to be a border? http://jsfiddle.net/3jHG8/1/

Comment: SVG-objects are a second option

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use [css box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) as follow:

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/3jHG8/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="ts"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ts {    
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-width:10px 10px 0px 10px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#f00 #f00 transparent #f00;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 0 #ddd;
}
```

[image]

or **box-shadow** only:

```
.ts {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
box-shadow: inset 0 10px 0 0 #f00,inset 10px 0 0 0 #f00,inset -10px 0 0 0 #f00, 0 20px 0 #ddd;
}
```

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3jHG8/4/)

[image]

Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), to emulates some text-shadow in older versions of in IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is not possible. Instead you can use something like this:

```
<div class="ts">sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text</div>

.ts {    
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 padding:10px;
 border-bottom:10px solid #dfd;
 background-color:#f00;
}
```

Hope this helps.