# Is it possible to have top-border take up full width in an element with other borders?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create this:

[image]

However, just using

```
border:10px solid green;
border-top:20px solid black;
```

Creates this image instead

[image]

There are pretty straight forward way to accomplish this.

You can use 2 elements
https://jsfiddle.net/5rnn328n/ 
Or a pseudo element 
https://jsfiddle.net/5rnn328n/2/

But both seem hacky.

Is it possible to accomplish this styling just a single element? ie. I have a single div and all I can use is inline styling.

```
<div style="[insert answer here]"></div>
```

Comment: I found an answer on another stackoverflow thread that may work for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534084/can-i-create-border-bottom-without-diagonal-corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property...

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 20px solid black;
  box-shadow: inset -20px 0px green, inset 20px 0px 0px green, inset 0 -20px 0px green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```